# How to fix git conflicy while merging files with git pull?

Tags: git

Every time I pull files via git, It keeps telling me that there is a conflict and pull can't be done.

how to force git to merge the remote changes in the file with the local one?

Note that there isn't any conflicts in the file

Comment: Can you show us the output of the `git status` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git fetch;
git rebase origin BRANCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. If you want to get the latest changes of the remote repository and base your changes on it, I would do the following:

```
git fetch <remote name>
git merge <remote name>/<branch name>
# resolve your conflicts
git commit
```

Or, which would be cleaner:

```
git fetch <remote name>
git checkout <my patches>
git rebase <remote name>/<branch name>
```

and while it is rebasing, you have to resolve the merge conflicts and do

```
git add <file>
git rebase --continue
```

after you fixed the conflict.

I used the `fetch` command in this case as it is more step-after-step like.